# Passing value into store as part of dispatch action returning undefined

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'd like to pass in a value into my store to update the current value.

What is the best way of doing it?

I've tried the below and setSelectedCourseContentUid is set to undefined. In my component:

```
  setSelectedCourseContentUid(uid: string): void {
    console.log(uid);
    this.store.dispatch(builderActions.hideAddContentMenu());
    this.store.dispatch(
      builderActions.setSelectedCourseContentUid({ selectedCourseContentUid: uid })
    );
  }
```

**builder.actions.ts**

```
export const setSelectedCourseContentUid = createAction(
  '[Builder] Set Selected Course Content Uid',
  props<{ selectedCourseContentUid: string }>()
);
```

**builder.reducer.ts**

```
export const builderReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(BuilderActions.setSelectedCourseContentUid, (state, { selectedCourseContentUid }) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      selectedCourseContentUid,
    };
  })
);
```

Comment: Where is selectedCourseContentUid supposed to come from? It should be passed as a prop in the action..

Comment: @MikeOne, sorry - question has been updated.

Comment: Right. So your action needs that prop as well: export const setSelectedCourseContentUid = createAction('[Builder] Set Selected Course Content Uid', props<{selectedCourseContentUid: string}>())

Comment: Yup, that's there too. I've just updated the action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `props` on your action:

```
export const setSelectedCourseContentUid = createAction('[Builder] Set Selected Course Content Uid', props<{ uid: String}>);
```

then access in your reducer:

```
export const builderReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(BuilderActions.setSelectedCourseContentUid, (state, {uid}) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      selectedCourseContentUid: uid,
    };
  })
);
```